# Why do these two string operations produce different output?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I have a program that is grabbing variables stored on the local file system and storing them in a variable.  I then attempt to URL encode them for use in a web API call.  I noticed however that several of my calls were producing errors and after researching it appears that the encoding is not working as expected.

This string encoding produces the correct result.

```
newstring = urllib.parse.quote(u"Müller".encode('utf8'))
print(newstring)
```

Output

```
M%C3%83%C2%BCller
```

However, this code does not produce the correct output

```
string2 = "Müller"
newstring2 = urllib.parse.quote(string2.encode('utf8'))
print(string2)
```

Output

```
MÃ¼ller
```

Any idea what the difference is here and how I can fix it so that the second bit of code produces accurate results?

Comment: I thought all strings in Python 3 were unicode by default.  Do you still need the `u` in `u"Müller"`?

Comment: They are @RocketHazmat `u''` is generally used (was added in `3.3`) when you need to simplify maintenance of `2.x`/`3.x` codebases. If the OP isn't aiming for that, the `u''` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to write `print(newstring2)` in your second example? That will produce the same output as in the first example.

```
In [1]: string2 = "Müller"
In [2]: print(urllib.parse.quote(string2.encode('utf8')))
M%C3%BCller
```